# Magento admin page helper not found error

Tags: magento-1.9, error, admin-panel, helper, fatal-error

I am trying to create new link in admin panel, which leads to helper not found error. My config files are as follows.

> app\code\local\Ddevs\Ebayaff\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ddevs_Ebayaff>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Ddevs_Ebayaff>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <add_category_attribute>
                <setup>
                    <module>Ddevs_Ebayaff</module>
                    <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </add_category_attribute>
        </resources>
        <helpers>
            <ebayaff>
                <class>Ddevs_Ebayaff_Helper</class>
            </ebayaff>
        </helpers>
    </global>

   <admin>
        <routers>

           <samplerouter1>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Ddevs_Ebayaff_AdminControllersHere</module>
                    <frontName>admin</frontName>

                    <modules>
                        <sintax after="Ddevs_Ebayaff_AdminControllersHere">Mage_Adminhtml</sintax>
                    </modules>
                </args>
           </samplerouter1>          



         </routers>     
    </admin>
```

> app\code\local\Ddevs\Ebayaff\etc\adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>

        <menu>
             <mymenu1 translate="title" module="ebayaff">
                <title>Ebay aff</title>
                <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                <children>

                    <myitem1 translate="title">
                        <title>Simple one column layout with custom template file assigned for viewsss</title>
                        <action>samplerouter1/FreakOut</action>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>                        
                    </myitem1>
                </children>
             </mymenu1>
        </menu>   
</config>
```

> app\code\local\Ddevs\Ebayaff\Helper\Data.php

```
<?php

class Ddevs_Ebayaff_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Data
{

}
```

And I am getting the following error.

> Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Ebayaff_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/html/demoshop/app/Mage.php on line 547

Comment: did you clear the cache?

Comment: have you create Ddevs_Ebayaf.xml at  app/etc/,modules

Comment: Yes, i have cleared the cache and also created module in app/etc/modules directory

Comment: In config.xml,there is no ending tag </config>

Comment: Remove `module="ebayaff"` in `adminhtml.xml` and then debug what's going on? I believe your `controller` naming is incorrect. It should be `AdminController.php` as I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly copy and paste these two files. The error "trying to create new link in admin panel, which leads to helper not found error" will be solved.

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Ddevs_Ebayaff>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Ddevs_Ebayaff>
</modules>
<global>
    <resources>
        <add_category_attribute>
            <setup>
                <module>Ddevs_Ebayaff</module>
                <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </add_category_attribute>
    </resources>
    <helpers>
        <ebayaff>
            <class>Ddevs_Ebayaff_Helper</class>
        </ebayaff>
    </helpers>
</global>

<admin>
    <routers>

       <ebayaff>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Ddevs_Ebayaff_AdminControllersHere</module>
                <frontName>admin</frontName>

                <modules>
                    <sintax after="Ddevs_Ebayaff_AdminControllersHere">Mage_Adminhtml</sintax>
                </modules>
            </args>
       </ebayaff>          

     </routers>     
</admin>
</config>
```

adminhtml.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>

    <menu>
         <mymenu1 translate="title" module="ebayaff">
            <title>Ebay aff</title>
            <sort_order>200</sort_order>
            <children>

                <myitem1 translate="title" module="ebayaff">
                    <title>Simple one column layout with custom template file assigned for viewsss</title>
                    <action>samplerouter1/FreakOut</action>  
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>                        
                </myitem1>
            </children>
         </mymenu1>
    </menu>   
</config>
```